# Android | Обновление RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

Мой адаптер содержит много элементов и выходит за пределы экрана по ширине. Для теста поместил в каждый элемент текст, в который вставляется случайное число, и заметил, что при прокрутке элемента за границы экрана и его возвращении число в нем обновляется. Есть ли способ отключить такое обновление?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть способ. Точно можно сказать только если вы код покажете, но, скорее всего, вы генерите число в onBindViewHolder. Он вызываться будет каждый раз при отрисовке ячейки, оттого и видите вы новое число. Сгенерируйте числа заранее, сохраните их в список, например и отображайте оттуда - так они меняться не будут

Answer (score 2):

поддерживаю ЮрийСПб и дополню:
вы можете отключить такое поведение если обернете в разметке ваш Ресайкл в NestetedSrollView.
но!
идея Ресайкла от его брата ListView как раз и заключается в том, отображение ячеек было "обновляемо".
если смотреть в корень, то у вас в Ресайкле всегда фиксированное число ячеек (на весь экран и + парочка вверху и внизу). а при скроле эти ячейки просто переиспользуются-перерисовываются.

как я уже сказал, обойти это можно с помощью NestetedScrollView, но если данных будет много - этот способ аукнется на производительности.